# Mutate a new column after grouping, summarizing, and evaluating for TRUE conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create the `output` data frame below after grouping and evaluating row conditions.  When I group and summarize the data frame, I can see that there are three instances of Ford that can be summarized as: Ford, 1 SUV, and 2 Truck.  Similarly, Honda can be summarized as Honda, 2 Sedan and Toyota can be summarized as Toyota, 1 Electric, and 1 Truck.  In addition, the number of instances after grouping would need to be summarized as well.  So in the case of Ford, it appears three times, Honda appears two times, and Toyota appears two times.  **I'm only interested in presenting cases where a Make appears more than once so Kia and Nissan would not be relevant in this set and are not displayed in the output.**  It would be nice if this could be in a form of a function as I plan to use it on a list of data frames.  That's not 100% necessary though as I can throw it in a function if it's not presented in that format.

**In:**

```
structure(list(Set = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Make = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Ford", "Honda", 
"Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota"), class = "factor"), Line = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("CSUV", "Electric", 
"Sedan", "SUV", "Truck"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

>
  Set   Make     Line
1   1   Ford    Truck
2   1  Honda    Sedan
3   1 Toyota    Truck
4   1   Ford      SUV
5   1 Nissan     CSUV
6   1  Honda    Sedan
7   1 Toyota Electric
8   1    Kia    Sedan
9   1   Ford    Truck

in %>% dplyr::group_by(Set,Make,Line) %>% dplyr::summarise(n = n()) %>% dplyr::arrange(Make)

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Set, Make [5]
    Set Make   Line         n
  <dbl> <fct>  <fct>    <int>
1     1 Ford   SUV          1
2     1 Ford   Truck        2
3     1 Honda  Sedan        2
4     1 Kia    Sedan        1
5     1 Nissan CSUV         1
6     1 Toyota Electric     1
7     1 Toyota Truck        1
```

**Output:**

```
structure(list(Set = c(1, 1, 1), Groups = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Ford_1Suv_2Truck", 
"Honda_1Sedan_1Van", "Toyota_1Electric_1Truck"), class = "factor"), 
    TotalInstances = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", 
    "3"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

> 
  Set              Groups Cases
1   1    Ford_1Suv_2Truck     3
2   1        Honda_2Sedan     2
3   1 Toyota_1Electric_1Truck 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the count with `summarise` and `arrange`ing, `filter` the rows based on the count column 'n' or the new count after dropping the last group, then `summarise` by pasteing (`str_c`) the 'n', 'Line' column, get the `sum` of 'n' to create 'Cases'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
in %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Set, Make, Line) %>%
    dplyr::arrange(Make) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise(Groups = str_c(n, Line, sep="", 
        collapse="_"), Cases = sum(n)) %>% 
    filter(n > 1) %>%        
    ungroup %>% 
    transmute(Set, Groups = str_c(Make, '_', Groups), Cases)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    Set Groups                  Cases
#  <dbl> <chr>                   <int>
#1     1 Ford_1SUV_2Truck            3
#2     1 Honda_2Sedan                2
#3     1 Toyota_1Electric_1Truck     2
```

---

We could make this faster with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
indt <- setDT(in)[, .(n = .N), .(Set, Make, Line)][order(Make)]
indt1 <- indt[indt[, .I[.N > 1|n > 1], .(Set, Make)]$V1] 
indt1[, .(Groups = paste0(n, Line, sep="", collapse="_"), Cases = sum(n)), .(Set, Make)][, Groups := str_c(Make, "_", Groups)]
```

Comment: this is a good solution and achieves exactly what I'm looking for. However, this has been very slow on a larger dataset. My dataset is approximately 300k rows and the operation has been running since roughly 8 a.m. this morning. can you think of any way to speed up the process by either eliminating any unnecessary operations or using a different library to group, summarize, and mutate?

Comment: @On_an_island May be a data.table method would be faster. Updated

Comment: it appears that `n()` in `filter(n() > 1|n > 1)` significantly slowed down your code. I ran it 8+ hours and by the time I came home from work it was still stuck at the filtering line. So I made the following change and it worked perfectly (fast): `dplyr::arrange(Make) %>% summarise(Groups = str_c(n, Line, sep="", collapse="_"), Cases = sum(n)) %>% filter(n > 1)`.  I'm accepting your answer but I recommend changing the filter operation and order.

Comment: @On_an_island thank you.  I updated the post with your change